# How to force an html attribute to change after everything (or object) has rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This isn't so much a question of how to replace an attribute value, but rather forcing it to change even after the last item on the page (or this object) has loaded.

The setup:
I'm using a content publishing platform - Hubspot - and I'm trying to leverage their CTA widget functionality. However, I don't want this particular CTA to redirect to another page (Hubspot UI requires a url) and I also want to add a data attribute which is used as my event listener.

The problem:
I have my jquery code that properly targets the CTA in question and is able to replace and add my values if I execute the code through the console, but as a script in a js file it does not work (file is placed last). So my thinking is this CTA object is actually being rendered after everything else even the js code I wrote.

Here's the outputted CTA

```
<a id="cta_button_UNIQUE-ID" class="cta_button book-a-demo-cta" 
href="https://SOME-LONG-TEMPORARY-URL-STRING" style="" title="Get a customized demo">
Get a customized demo</a>
```

and here's my jquery

```
$('#cta_button_UNIQUE-ID').attr('href', '#').attr('data-ix', 'show-
book-demo-modal');
```

Again, if I execute the code through the console everything works as I want it to, but not as a standalone script. Also, I don't believe this to be a js file issue since other code in the same file executes and works.

Many thanks!

Comment: The canonical way to get something to run after page load in jQuery is via the `document.ready` event. `$(document).ready(function () { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: No need for `ready` if the file is at the end of `body` (I *think* that's what the OP means by "...file is placed last..." but I could be mistaken).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think it's appearing later, just poll until you see it (giving up after a reasonable time if it hasn't appeared):

```
var start = Date.now();
(function updateElement() {
    var el = $('#cta_button_UNIQUE-ID');
    if (!el.length) {
        // Not found (yet)
        if (Date.now() - start > 30000) {
            // Give up
        } else {
            setTimeout(updateElement, 250);
        }
    } else {
        // Got it, do the update
        el.attr('href', '#').attr('data-ix', 'show-
book-demo-modal');
    }
})();
```

...probably all wrapped in an IIFE to avoid making `start` a global.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!